# After rewriting RoundCube URLs, CSS, JS, and image resource links are broken

Tags: mod-rewrite, clean-urls, resources

What I'd like to do is that I want to make nice URLs for my roundcube pages with `.htaccess`.

For example:

```
RewriteRule    ^latest/$    index.php?_action=news&type=latest  [NC,L]
```

If I go to this page, the rewrite happens, so my latest new shows, but all the other resources broken.

This is because all of them coded as relative URLs. Unfortunately I have no influence to rewrite them to absolute urls, because roundcube template engine handle the output from the core, or from plugins.

I am a programmer, not a sysadmin, so I have only basic knowledge about rewrite rules.

Can you help me with this guys?

**EDIT:** This is what I've figure out, but for some reason it not works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^latest/$    index.php?_action=news&type=latest  [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRUle ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%/$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

So my idea is that if not directory found, apply it to my directory, this works.

The seconf is if no file like that, remove the first directory, and redirect that file to the root. For some reason it not works.

Anybody?

**EDIT2**: Wow, it works, this is the good solution:

```
RewriteRUle ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

No need `%` sign (typo) after server name. I hope there are no side effects.

[image]

Comment: If you change the URLs, you also need to change the links to those URLs.  Have you modified RoundCube to link to your new clean URL?

Comment: Nope, I did not change anything. What should I change? I know htaccess more or less, what I'd like to achive is that I should not change anything. Ok, dreaming is a good thing, but I think, maybe there is an option to force roundcube (from htaccess) to resolve these somehow to the base url. Do you think, is there a solution?

Comment: I doubt that this can be done with just .htaccess.  I don't know of a way of doing this without adjusting the setting on your CMS or editing its code.   I don't know RoundCube at all, so I can't really help with it, but maybe somebody else here knows it better.

Comment: Do you need the slash suffix at the end of the "nice" URL? Where exactly are these nice URLs being used? Are you simply linking to these from an external page, or are you wanting to change the URLs throughout the RoundCube app?

Comment: @MrWhite I have several categories for news, like tech, latest, etc... Now I am using this `?_action=news&type=tech` for this. I'd like to turn it to '/tech/'. These are only on the pages where user has not logged in. Thats all, my above example works, but every other resources broken.

Comment: Updated original question.